# matplotlib can display in python3 but not pyhon2

Tags: matplotlib

I installed matplotlib in both python3 and python2.

same program run both python3 and python2, only python3 can display window

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

I check the backends is "TkAgg", and python-thinker installed.

Comment: That is independent of python 2 or 3. It will work in both versions. If it is not in your specific case, make sure to provide more information about versions, how you run the code etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I installed matplotlib using `sudo -H pip install matplotlib` and `sudo -H pip3 install matplotlib`. I use `python test.py` and `python3 test.py` to run the program. The fanil result is python3 can show the graph but python2 cannot show the graph